# Pymongoで丸ごとdictをアップデートしたいです。

Tags: python, python3, mongodb

元のデータにこれらが入っているとします。

```
usa1 = {1: 'Jay-Z', 2: 'Smap', 3: {'age': 20, 'tall': 144} }
data = {'A': 'okada', 'B': 'satou', 'C': 'Yamane', 'D': usa1}
db.student.insert(data)
```

一部を変更します

```
usa2 = {1: 'Jay-Z', 2: 'Smap', 3: {'age': 33, 'tall': 181} }
data = {'A': 'okada', 'B': 'satou', 'C': 'Yamane', 'D': usa2}
db.student.update(data)
```

上記ではエラーになってしまうので、一度空の`student2`に`insert`して`student`を削除してから`student`に`insert`するということをやっているんですが、他にスマートな方法はありませんか？

```
student2 = list(db.student.find())
db.student.remove()
db.student.insert(student2)
```

Comment: `$set` を使えば良いのではないでしょうか。例えば、`db.student.update({'A': 'okada', 'B': 'satou', 'C': 'Yamane'}, {$set:data})` などとします。

Comment: すみません、フィールドABCは全てデタラメでもっと複雑なコレクションとなっておりますので丸ごとUPDATEしたいです。

Comment: その場合は `db.student.update({}, {$set:data})` となりますけれども、これですと全てのレコードに `data` の内容がセットされてしまう事になります。何らかの条件を付与して、更新対象のレコードを絞り込むべきだとは思いますが…

Comment: ありがとうございます。`db.student.update({}, {$set:data})`が正解でした。回答したいただければ幸いです

Comment: GridFS APIを利用することで可能になりました。

Comment: 了解です。コメント内容に一部間違いがありましたので、訂正して回答したいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントでは勘違いをしていたのですが、

```
db.student.update({}, {$set: data})
```

の場合、条件にマッチするドキュメント(RDB のレコードに相当)の内、`ObjectId` が最小のものだけが更新されます(`updateOne()`と同等)。条件にマッチする全てのドキュメントを更新する場合は、`multi` パラメータを `true` にセットするか、

```
db.student.update({}, {$set: data}, {multi: true})
```

`updateMany()` を使用します。

```
db.student.updateMany({}, {$set: data})
```

また、今回は `'D'` フィールドだけの変更ですので、

```
db.student.update({}, {$set: {'D': usa2}})
```

とする事もできます。この場合は他のフィールドは更新されず元のままとなります。

Comment: 大変参考になりました。その場合私は、`update_many`と打っていたのでエラーが出ていて気づきませんでした。